# Retrieving just the joined entities from Core Data

Tags: core-data, xcode6

I have a movie showtimes entity which has a one-to-one relationship to a movie entity. The inverse (movie -> movie showtime) relationship is a one-to-many relationship. If a movie is deleted, the associated movie showtimes will also be deleted, but if a movie showtime is deleted the associated movie will stay. (Not sure how much of that is relevant but wanted to clarify the situation as much as I could)

Now, is there a way to query Core Data to get only the unique movies for which I have showtimes?

Is it possible to select from the movie showtimes and somehow restrict the results to just the associated unique movies? Or would selecting from the movie entity bring back only the movies with a matching row in the movie showtime entity?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Write a fetch request on Movie with no restrictions, and you'll get all Movie instances.

Comment: Thanks, although I was after just movies with showtimes against them (apologies if I didn't make that clear).

Comment: Okay, in the end I wrote a fetch request to pull in movies with the predicate of there having to be a matching showtime entity, i.e. !(ANY(showtime) = Nil) seemed to do the trick. Is this the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Taking your questions in turn:

> Now, is there a way to query Core Data to get only the unique movies for which I have showtimes?

You could use a predicate to select `movies` where the count of `showtimes` is greater than zero:

```
"showtimes.@count > 0"
```

> Is it possible to select from the movie showtimes and somehow restrict the results to just the associated unique movies?

If you have (courtesy of your first query) an array (say `scheduledMovies`) of `movies` which have `showtimes`, then you can fetch the associated `showtimes` using a predicate like this:

```
 "movie IN %@", scheduledMovies
```

> Or would selecting from the movie entity bring back only the movies with a matching row in the movie showtime entity?

If you fetch `movies`, then you will get ALL `movies`, unless you specify a predicate as per your first question.  But if you fetch `showtimes`, you can get an array of the associated `movies` using key value coding with the key:

```
"@distinctUnionOfObjects.movie"
```

The resulting array will not have any `movies` with no `showtimes`.  (The first part of this key removes any duplicates, since several `showtimes` might have the same `movie`).